# What's wrong with Rails's Date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, date

I ran into this non-sense problem this morning in Rails 3.2 console. I'm under MacOS 10.10, my timezone is +7.

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.12)
irb(main):001:0> Date.today
=> Sun, 16 Nov 2014
irb(main):002:0> Date.yesterday
=> Fri, 14 Nov 2014
irb(main):003:0>
```

Everything is fine with original Ruby Date:

```
irb(main):006:0> Date.today
=> #<Date: 2014-11-16 ((2456978j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
irb(main):007:0> Date.today.prev_day
=> #<Date: 2014-11-15 ((2456977j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
irb(main):008:0>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I can't even think of what's wrong with this. :(

Comment: Sure, I'm able to reproduce this in `1.9.3-p550`.  Sorry didn't test others as this console was already open!

Comment: Date#today comes from original Ruby, Rails has only #current, #yesterday and #tomorrow instead of redefining #today so they are inconsistent. It's weird to see this happens in a grown up web framework like Rails.

Answer (score 5):

From the bug report here: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/6410#ticket-6410-8

> This is a subtle one - Date.yesterday uses Date.current which will use the time zone whereas Date.today doesn't. If you set your time zone to one where it's tomorrow already (e.g. Europe/Berlin as I type this) then you can get Date.today == Date.yesterday:
>
> > Time.zone = "Europe/London"
> >     => "Europe/London"
> >     Date.today == Date.yesterday
> >     => false
> >
> > Time.zone = "Europe/Berlin"
> >     => "Europe/Berlin"
> >     Date.today == Date.yesterday
> >     => true